# PLM package: Difference between PMG and PCCE function

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

What is the difference of pmg and PCCE function in package PLM? details of both is almost same in the description. I wanted to perform mg, pmg and CCE mg test on panel data using plm function. I thought pmg and pcce are the right function. can someone please confirm which function I shall use?

The reference provided for PMG function is of 2006, which talks about Common correlated effect (CCE) mean group or pool. I woder if PMG is without CCE in plm package or with CCE.

Comment: You could file a ticket directly at the author's [GitHub](https://github.com/ycroissant/plm/issues).

Answer (score 0):

From the `plm` packages first vignette we see both function can estimate the common
correlated effects MG (CCEMG) model (and also from `?plm::pmg` and `?plm::pcce`):

> `pmg`: estimators for mean groups (MG), demeaned MG (DMG) and common
> correlated effects MG (CCEMG) for heterogeneous panel models

> `pcce`: estimators for common correlated effects mean groups (CCEMG) and
> pooled (CCEP) for panel data with common factors

So, let's see if we can get the same estimates from both function with the parametrisation to estimate a "CCEMG" model:

```
library(plm)
data("Produc", package = "plm")
pProduc <- pdata.frame(Produc)
form <- log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp
pccemgmod   <- pcce(form, data = pProduc, model = "mg")
pmgccemgmod <- pmg (form, data = pProduc, model = "cmg")
common <- intersect(names(pccemgmod[["coefficients"]]), names(pmgccemgmod[["coefficients"]]))
(coef_pccemgmod   <- round(pccemgmod[["coefficients"]][common],   digits = 7))
#>  log(pcap)    log(pc)   log(emp)      unemp 
#>  0.0899850  0.0335784  0.6258657 -0.0031178
(coef_pmgccemgmod <- round(pmgccemgmod[["coefficients"]][common], digits = 7))
#>  log(pcap)    log(pc)   log(emp)      unemp 
#>  0.0899850  0.0335784  0.6258659 -0.0031178
```

You get the same results. `pcce(., model = "mg")` and `pmg(., model = "cmg")` estimate the same model but internally in a different way, hence coefficients might slightly diverge due to numerical precision when you look at many digits.

In the example output above, I have only stated the coefficents common to both model objects. For the "`pmg`-way" (object `pmgccemgmod`), you get an intercept and the coefficients of auxiluary variables used for that estimation approach as well, so the full picture is:

```
> (pmgccemgmod)

Model Formula: log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)     log(pcap)       log(pc)      log(emp)         unemp         y.bar log(pcap).bar   log(pc).bar  log(emp).bar 
   -0.6741754     0.0899850     0.0335784     0.6258659    -0.0031178     1.0038005    -0.0491919    -0.0033198    -0.6978359 
    unemp.bar 
    0.0025544
```